# got trap, how to log in?

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication

```
private void d_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string connstring = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\it155.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            string snumber = txtSnumber.Text;
            SqlCommand get = new SqlCommand(@"Select from IStudent where SNumber ='" + txtSnumber.Text + "'", conn);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

given the start of the code which is written above, what i plan to do is to be able to log in using id number datatype varchar(11) in the sql database which was to be entered in the txtSnumber but aside that i cant figure out how to check whether the id number entered is correct or not and if it is correct, the information corresponding to that id number enetered is supposed to show in the their corresponding textboxes. please help me, thanks

Comment: I strongly recommend that you remove that try/catch block. It will make you ignore all exceptions, which is not what you want to do.

Answer (score 5):

Your sql statement is prone to SQL Injection. Is terrible practice to concatenate SQL like this. Instead do something like this:

```
string snumber = txtSnumber.Text;
SqlCommand get = new SqlCommand(@"Select from IStudent where SNumber =@User", conn);

get.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User",snumber);
```

Now, in order to check whether the record was found or not, you do this:

```
using(IDataReader reader =  get.ExecuteReader())
{
       if (reader.HasRows)
       {
          //information correct. Do something
       }
}
```

Comment: Just for my understanding and curiousness, how your solution on using @user and parameters statements avoid SQL injection? I mean your indirectly assinging textBox value right?

Comment: @zenwalker parameters are escaped automatically; concatenation of strings are passed as raw text to the DBMS. There are more benefits for using parametrized queries, such as the fact that execution plans can be cached whereas raw sql statements can't be.

Comment: int this line "get.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User",snumber);", what is @User supposed to be exactly? is it the name of the textbox where the id number is supposed to be written?

Comment: +1. This Icarus is far more wise than his ancient Greek namesake.

Comment: @erwinmendoza "@User" is the parameter name, I meant it as an example. You can put anything you want: "@x", "@ss", etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it by using a [DataReader()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

```
   SqlCommand get = new SqlCommand(@"Select from IStudent where SNumber ='" + txtSnumber.Text + "'", conn); 
   SqlDataReader myReader = get.ExecuteReader();
  if (myReader.HasRows)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("ID is valid");
    while (myReader.Read())
      //Do something here        
  }
  else
    MessageBox.Show("Given ID is Invalid.");
```

EDIT:

While calling ExecuteReader() method you put the following argument inside it, so that when ever you close the connection the datareader also automatically closes.

```
SqlDataReader myReader = get.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```

Comment: there is an error saying that it was not opened. i tried putting "conn.Open();" above the SqlCommand line but there is still an error that pops up

Comment: when you got that error? while reading the values from datareader or some other?